# What does "the movement" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, antebellum

Elizabeth says to southern plantation slave:

> Elizabeth: My father kept insistin'. He said you were spreadin' such
> filth! I told him you weren't worth the risk...but he couldn't resist,
> **the movement** be damned! He just had to have you. Every single one of
> you I picked, except for you. His favorite girl.

What does "the movement" refer to?